# Choose higher value based off column value between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

question to choose value based on two df.

```
>>> df[['age','name']]
    age   name
0    44   Anna
1    22    Bob
2    33  Cindy
3    44  Danis
4    55  Cindy
5    66  Danis
6    11   Anna
7    43    Bob
8    12  Cindy
9    19  Danis
10   11   Anna
11   32   Anna
12   55   Anna
13   33   Anna
14   32   Anna

>>> df2[['age','name']]
   age   name
5   66  Danis
4   55  Cindy
0   44   Anna
7   43    Bob
```

expected result is all rows that value 'age' is higher than df['age'] based on column 'name.

expected result

```
    age   name
12   55   Anna
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, use merge and filter dataframe:

```
df.merge(df2, on='name', suffixes={'','_y'}).query('age > age_y')[['name','age']]
```

Output:

```
   name  age
4  Anna   55
```

---

IIUC, you can use this to find the max age of all names:

```
pd.concat([df,df2]).groupby('name')['age'].max()
```

Output:

```
name
Anna     55
Bob      43
Cindy    55
Danis    66
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: possible to get age only higher than df2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
index = df[df['age'] > age].index
df.loc[index]
```

Comment: Have you tried it and does it work? If answered with "yes/yes"... then rephrase the answer to show (more) confidence.  In all other cases add context. Now its pure code...

Answer (score 0):

One solution comes to my mind is `merge` and `drop`

```
df.merge(df2, on='name', suffixes=('', '_y')).query('age.gt(age_y)', engine='python')[['age','name']]

Out[175]:
   age  name
4   55  Anna
```

Comment: getting an error TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: I figured out. I added `engine='python'` to fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few edge cases you don't mention how you would like to resolve, but generally what you want to do is iterate down the df and compare ages and use the larger. You could do so in the following manner:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['age', 'name'])
for x in len(df):
    if df['age'][x] > df2['age'][x]:
        df3['age'][x] = df['age'][x]
        df3['name'][x] = df['name'][x] 
    else:
        df3['age'][x] = df2['age'][x]
        df3['name'][x] = df2['name'][x]
```

Although you will need to modify this to reflect how you want to resolve names that are only in one list, or if the lists are of different sizes.